# Simulating DataSet for a DCE

Tags: multinomial-logit

I would like to simulate a dataset of a Discrete Choice Experiment (DCE) that would be analysed with a simple multinomial logit model. For example, the DCE could concern consumers preferences for two different food items with different attributes (e.g., calories, fat content, price). I was thinking to use a Monte Carlo simulation, but on the forum I have read different suggestion. Any help?
Also I was thinking to include some interaction term such as ATTRIBUTE X AGE, ATTRIBUTE X GENDER.